# How do I enable Shift Lock? (Sticky shift key)

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

I want to map one of my keys the shift lock key. In my understanding, the shift lock key is a kind of a 'sticky' shift key: it remains pressed, shifting all keys of the layout until pressed again.

It is similar to the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key, except that it affects all keys, including the ones in the numeric row.

I am trying to use `setxkbmap -option ...` to handle this.

I found these promising rules in in `/usr/local/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`:

```
  caps:internal        Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:internal_nocancel Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift doesn't affect Caps Lock
  caps:shift           Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:shift_nocancel  Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift doesn't affect Caps Lock
  caps:capslock        Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters
  caps:shiftlock       Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock (affects all keys)
  shift:breaks_caps    Shift cancels Caps Lock
  shift:both_capslock  Both Shift keys together toggle Caps Lock
  shift:both_capslock_cancel Both Shift keys together activate Caps Lock, one Shift key deactivates
  shift:both_shiftlock Both Shift keys together toggle ShiftLock
```

So,

```
setxkbmap -option shift:both_shiftlock
```

And I try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> (and releasing it), and typing other characters. No effect. All characters lowercase. If I hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and type other keys, it acts as you'd normally expect.

I tried `caps:shift`, `shift:both_shiftlock` and `caps:shiftlock` but none of them have any effect as far as I can tell. What's wrong?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it read ***Both** Shift keys **together.*** So `shift:both_shiftlock` works, but that's no good since those two keys are terribly far away from each other.

Comment: Okay, it seems my `ctrl:swapcaps` is one problem. `swapcaps` and `shiftlock` don't play well together at all.

Comment: So: `caps:shiftlock` works but only if caps lock is left of the 'A' key, not left of the space bar. Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to turn <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> into Shift Lock, thanks to a [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/414060):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_Lock"
```

The following turns my left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key into shift lock:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Shift_Lock"
```

To make the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key lock, use

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = Shift_Lock"
```

Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, use

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Shift_Lock"
```

When Shift Lock is active, your keyboard's Caps Lock and Scroll Lock LEDs should both be lit.

Comment: In that case please edit your question title to reflect the answer (and re-tag it `xmodmap`) as otherwise the obvious answer is to use the `shift:both_shiftlock`

Comment: @don_crissti I'm confused. The question and its title match my answer -- the only difference is the tool used. `setxkbmap` apparently does not have the capability to get sticky shift keys except in two specific configurations.

Comment: Well, ... the title says : _"How do I enable Shift Lock? (Sticky shift key)"_ and the answer is _"use `setxkbmap` with `shift:both_shiftlock`"_ though what you actually want is to _shiftlock_ with a custom key (or custom key combo)

Comment: @don_crissti All I asked was how to get Shift Lock working -- any method. To me, the most desirable/familiar method is a sticky Shift key. You may write a second answer about `setxkbmap` if you think it improves this question. (I think it does.)