# Sticky shift key

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, accessibility

Is there a way to get "sticky" shift, so that I can (sequentially) type

- <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> to get `%`
- <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> to get `#`
- <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> to get `R`

There's [shift lock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224827) in X11, but that doesn't cancel after producing a shifted character.

Comment: That's the normal mapping for any US keyboard. Do you have a different keyboard installed? Where does your distro (please add a tag) ask for which keyboard you have? Alternatively, you can use `xmodmap` to generate any sort of mapping you want.

Comment: ... presuming that it is even X Window System user interfaces that you are talking about.  You haven't stated that, either.

Comment: Assuming X, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224827).

Comment: Do mean sticky shift, where you release the shift key before typing 5 , in order to get % ?

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement forms part of the [AccessX](http://cita.disability.uiuc.edu/software/accessx/freewareaccessx.php) accessibility features that has been packaged for X11 into the `xkbset` command which you should be able to find in the package of the same name.

The usage is

```
xkbset sticky twokey
```

After this, every time you press and release the Shift key, the following single typed character will be shifted. It applies similarly to the Control key.  To cancel the action use

```
xkbset -sticky twokey
```

Comment: the above is what I wanted, prretty sure.  Without anything following the     "xkbset", a whole bunch of strings are output to my konsole.  Proves only that it is hard to explain utilities like this.  Thanks very much.